# React Handle multiple forms within a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a page with dynamic tabs and each of them have a form input. There is a common Submit for each of these forms. As of now, I have a separate component for each of the forms and each of them have multiple user inputs.

```
<div id="#parentComponent">
{myForm1 && <div><MyForm1 {...props}/></div>}
{myForm2 && <MyForm2 {...props} /></div>}
<div>
<input type="submit">
```

Now, my question is on Submit (common and in the parent component), I want to be able to access each of the form input values. But as of now, my inactive tab/component gets destroyed and only the active tab/component is there in the DOM.

What is the best way to handle this? Also should there be any preference to controlled/uncontrolled components to handle this use case ?

As of now, I am using the uncontrolled form for these form inputs (using the useformcontext)

Answer (score 2):

I would keep the state in a higher order component, and update it by any change withing the forms.
I would pass down a setFormsData function to every form, and add their data on every change, keeping the old state, like this:

```
const handleOnChange = value => setFormsData(oldFormData => {...oldFormData, ...value})
```

You can also use a redux store if you wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot...With the above approach, how do I manage if the child section/form (so the form inputs) get destroyed when another child section/form is active ? so basically user can move back and forth between different tabs/forms and at a time only one tab/form is active...Any psuedu ref/code would be really great...Also, to add, I am planning to use redux-toolkit for the overall global state management.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it helped :) The fact is if the children are destroyed, their contribution will stay in the parent's state. Redux toolkit is just amazing. It always has simplified my life. If you needed any help with that, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Oh k...So I was wondering if it is a good practice to destroy child components if we intend to utilize the value (may be on tab revisit Or on submit)

Comment: I really don't know if it is a good practice to destroy the component or keep it on your DOM and make it heavy. I remember when I used Tabs from Antd, it used to destroy the tabs' content. All that has to be done, is to keep the inserted data somewhere (server, localStorage, higher order component (hoc) or redux store) and populate each form with the prefilled data, when the form is summoned (rendered). I thought also of suggesting to make a multistage form (where you fill form A, and go to form B), but realized it is essentially same as what you are already doing.